# Splitting a command line in C

Tags: c, parsing

Is this a good C program for splitting a command line without doing any expansion on it? Don't worry too much about `main()` and the output -- those are for testing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <assert.h>
void pullwhitespace(char **input);
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
        if (argc != 2) {
                fputs("Must have exactly one command line argument\n", stderr);
                return 64;
        }
        char *input = argv[1];
        char *outstring = malloc(strlen(argv[1]) + 1);
        char *outptr = outstring;
        char a;
        pullwhitespace(&input);
NORMAL:
        /* We are in an unquoted part of the input */
        switch ((a = *input++))
        {
        case ' ' :
        case '\t':
                *outptr++ = '\0';
                pullwhitespace(&input);
                goto NORMAL;
        case '\n':
        case '\0':
                goto DONE;
        case '\\':
                if (((a = *input++)) == '\n') {
                        break;
                } else if (a) {
                        *outptr++ = a;
                        goto NORMAL;
                } else {
                        goto FAIL;
                }
        case '\'':
                goto QUOTE;
        case '"':
                goto DQUOTE;
        default:
                *outptr++ = a;
                goto NORMAL;
        }
        assert(0);
QUOTE:
        /* We are in a single quoted string */        
        while (((a = *input++)) != '\'') {
                if (a) {
                        *outptr++ = a;
                } else {
                        goto FAIL;
                }
        }
        goto NORMAL;
DQUOTE:
        /* We are in a double quoted string */
        switch ((a = *input++))
        {
        case '\0':
                goto FAIL;
        case '\\':
        {
                char b = *input++;
                switch (b)
                {
                case '\0':
                        goto FAIL;
                default:
                        *outptr++ = a;              
                case '"':              
                case '\\':
                        *outptr++ = b;
                case '\n':
                        break;
                }
        }
        goto DQUOTE;
        default:
                *outptr++ = a;
                goto DQUOTE;
        case '"':
                goto NORMAL;
        }
        assert(0);
FAIL:
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: Invalid string input\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
        assert(0);
DONE:
        *outptr++ = '\0';
        *outptr++ = '\0';
        errno = 0;
        fwrite(outstring, 1, (size_t)(outptr - outstring), stdout);
        int error = errno;
        if(ferror(stdout)) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: write error: %s\n", argv[0], strerror(error));
                return 1;
        }                
        fflush(stdout);
        if ( errno != 0) {                
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: write error: %s\n", argv[0], strerror(error));
                return 1;
        }
        return 0;
}
void pullwhitespace (char **inputptr)
{
        char *input = *inputptr;
        char a;
        while (( a = *input)) {
                if (a != ' ' && a != '\t') {
                        return;
                }
                input++;
        }
}
```

I know that it is FULL of goto statements (more than every other program I have ever made put together) -- is that okay?

The reason for the `goto` statements is that this is meant as a lightweight state machine. Intended applications include parsing command line arguments or (possibly - this is far fetched) for the parser (not supporting code) to be the basis of a kernel module to parse shebang lines, allowing multiple arguments to be passed to a shebang interpreter.

Comment: No, it's a [lexer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2842809/89999) :)

Comment: What test cases have you tried this with? If you haven't got a set of tests for complex functions like this that it consistently passes, my default opinion is that it's not production ready.

Comment: Why so many `goto`s?  Those are frowned upon in C... in fact, I'm frowning right now. :-(

Comment: That is because this is a state machine.

Comment: You should be able to write a state machine without gotos.

Comment: `goto`s need not be feared irrationally, and I've seen them in in lexers before, including in the CPython lexer ([tokenizer.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/26d92a21f6cf/Parser/tokenizer.c)), that said, it's good to figure out the alternatives, which you may end up liking more.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that this code actually works. Especially `pullwhitespace` doesn't do what you probably intended (hint: it doesn't modify the argument, it makes a copy of the pointer and advances it). Have you tested it before submitting it for review here?

Anyway: You might want to have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133214/is-there-a-typical-state-machine-implementation-pattern) for alternative ways to implement a state machine. You approach is similar to Remo.D's answer in the linked question but I think his macros make it more readable.

A few things I noticed:

1. When you are in `NORMAL` and read a white space you do this `*outptr++ = '\0';` Given that strings in C are NULL terminated character sequences this seems dodgy as it will terminate the output right there unless you tell someone to read further by supplying a length. If you intend to split on white space then you should store the results in a `char **` like `argv`.
2. Again in `NORMAL`:

   ```
   case '\\':
           if (((a = *input++)) == '\n') {
                   break;
           } else if (a) {
                   *outptr++ = a;
                   goto NORMAL;
           } else {
                   goto FAIL;
           }
   ```

   So if you find a `\` followed by a newline you `break` the `switch` which is followed by an `assert(0)`. Normally `assert` should be used to state invariants as "this function expects this condition to be true and it is probably a bug in the program if it is not". Specifically `assert(0)` should be used as "should never execute this code path". It seems weird that external user input can trigger an `assert` just because the program doesn't like he input. Especially since you have a `FAIL` state anyway.

   Also the `else` condition evaluation depends on the side effect of the `if` condition evaluation - not very nice. You should read the next character first in a separate line and then evaluate. This makes it much clearer. So this case could probably have been written as:

   ```
   case '\\':
           a = *input++;
           if (a && a != '\n') {
                  *outptr++ = a;
                  goto NORMAL;
           }
           goto FAIL;
   ```
3. If you are in `DQUOTE` and encounter a `\` then you read another character from the input. However that character simply gets swallowed because in the default case you do this: `*outptr++ = a;` which will write the `\` to the output and skip the current character (held in `b`).

Answer (score 1):

Comments about `pullwhitespace()`:

1. Code is broken.  Needs work to *update* `*inputptr`.
2. Needs better name than `inputptr`.  Maybe `string_ptr`.  Hmm, no *much* better.
3. Rather than define "whitespace" as `' '` and `'\t'`, use the C definition of whitesapce.
4. [Edit] Deleted `const` susggestion.

   ```
   void pullwhitespace (char **inputptr) {
     char *input = *inputptr;
     char a;
     while ((a = *input) != '\0') {
       if (!isspace((unsigned char) a)) {
         break;
       }
       input++;
     }
     *inputptr = input;
   }
   ```

If one accept using the C standard `isspace()` further simplification results in

```
    void pullwhitespace (char **inputptr) {
      char *input = *inputptr;
      while (isspace(*input)) input++;
      *inputptr = input;
    }
```

Comment: Adding `const` to the definition of parameter `inputptr` doesn't work the way you'd expect (see http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html). You have also modified the function in ways that make it worse than the original (first commented line).

Comment: @William Morris I have seen the error of my ways concerning `const` and corrected  `while ((a = *(*inputptr)) != '\0')`. Please detail about your 2nd point, what is worse?

Comment: @William Morris I also see that `isspace()` needs an `unsigned char` or `EOF`.  Is that your concern?

Comment: The original code had `char *input = *inputptr;` and then de-referenced `input`, whereas your code omits that and uses eg `*(*inputptr)`, which is more difficult to read (and hence worse). I would have made the OP's `input` a `const`, ie: `const char *input = *inputptr;`.  Also it is arguable that the OP might have wanted just space and tab to be treated instead of all white-space (although I haven't read the code to see).

Comment: BTW, when you use @ to quote a name, there should be no spaces in the name. With @WilliamMorris I get a notification, with the space, I don't :-)

Comment: @WilliamMorris  The change from `*input` to `*(*inputptr)` is a functional change.  OP's original function does _not_ work.  It nicely iterates looking for spaces and does `input++`.  Unfortunately, this has no effect on `*inputptr` and thus the function does _nothing_ except kill CPU time. The method, I've shown, though "more difficult to read", is the correct functionality.  One could instead do the `char *input = *inputptr` and then just before the returning (in 2 places) do `*inputptr = input`.  This is my point #1 "Needs work to conditionally update *inputptr".  Sorry if not more clear.

Comment: +1. I was aware that the original fn was broken, but it hadn't occurred to me that your `(*inputptr)++;` fixed that.  Now I see why you did it that way.  All the same I've been programming C for (too) many years, so maybe that proves my point that it was not optimally readable :-)  I like your latest version better, but for me, I'd replace `pullwhitespace` with `s += strspn(s, " \t");`

Comment: @WilliamMorris nice solution with `s += strspn(s, " \t")`.  Its better than calling a function `pullwhitespace()` that does not pull "whitepsace" as defined by C, but "whitespace" defined locally.

Answer (score 0):

This parser is not that complicated, you don't need jumps.
My example below ignores some corner cases, just showing the priciple.
You can expand it to your needs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char *s, *e;

    for (e = argv[1]; *e; s = e) {
        while (isspace(*e)) e++;

        if (*e == '\"') {
            for (s = ++e; *e && *e != '\"'; e++);
            if (!*e) return 1; // missing closing quote
        } else if (*e == '\'') {
            for (s = ++e; *e && *e != '\''; e++);
            if (!*e) return 1; // missing closing quote
        } else {
            for (s = e; *e && !isspace(*e); e++);
        }
        printf("'%.*s'\n", (int)(e - s), s);

        if (*e == '\"' || *e == '\'')
            e++; // advance after closing quote
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think this answer would be a lot more helpful with some discussion on how this approach differs from the original, and why you think it's better.

Comment: Your code doesn't cope with escape-sequences in double- or single-quoted strings like the original.